# Mock class attribute

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

Let's say I have some class:

```
class Worker:

_processor: Processor

def set_processor(self, processor: Processor):
    self._processor = processor

def start_work(self, data: bytes):
    self._processor.parse(data)
```

It's pretty simple to test `set_processor` method, smth like that:

```
def test_set_processor():
    mock_processor = Mock()
    worker = Worker()
    worker.set_processor(mock_processor)

    assert worker._processor == mock_processor
```

We just pass mock into `set_processor` method and check if `self._processor` equals mock now.

But how can I test `start_work` method? I want to be sure that `self._processor` will be called with `data`?
If I try to patch `_processor` attribute I'm getting error.

Comment: Why do you need to patch anything? You can test this whole thing in one go: pass the mock to the set method, call the other method and assert the mock got exercised as expected.

Comment: Yes, sounds good. But I think it's not bad idea to test separate every method. Now I solved with set _processor to mock directly: worker._processor = Mock(). And then call method and check if mock were called.

Comment: But then you're interfering with internal implementation details as part of the test. Test through the public API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`worker.py`:

```py
from typing import Any

Processor = Any


class Worker:
    _processor: Processor

    def set_processor(self, processor: Processor):
        self._processor = processor

    def start_work(self, data: bytes):
        self._processor.parse(data)
```

`test_worker.py`:

```py
import unittest
from worker import Worker
from unittest.mock import Mock


class TestWorker(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_set_processor(self):
        mock_processor = Mock()
        worker = Worker()
        worker.set_processor(mock_processor)
        assert worker._processor == mock_processor
        worker.start_work(b'')
        mock_processor.parse.assert_called_once_with(b'')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
(venv) ☁  python-codelab [master] ⚡  coverage report -m                                                                                              
Name                                        Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/59202648/test_worker.py      13      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/59202648/worker.py            8      0   100%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                          21      0   100%
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59202648